# libsql-experimental library installation error

Tags: python

```
Collecting libsql-experimental
  Using cached libsql_experimental-0.0.26.tar.gz (34 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: libsql-experimental
  Building wheel for libsql-experimental (pyproject.toml) ... error
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for libsql-experimental
Failed to build libsql-experimental
ERROR: Could not build wheels for libsql-experimental, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I'm installing pip install libsql-experimental to write tables in database of turso
it is throwing an installation error my version of python is 3.10.10

Comment: Are you using windows?

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the same problem...
Windows was the issue, on WSL env works fine